# Why does JavaScript make it so difficult to check if an image is loaded?

Tags: javascript

Why is it so difficult to check if an img has loaded in JavaScript? With other languages this can be easily solved by doing a loop, and breaking when the image has loaded.

Here is a function that returns a loaded img after passing a file path. Nothing other than onload seems to work to check if the image has loaded. I am unable to use img.complete or any other method with a loop checking each time until the load has completed because it simply does not work (the browser will hang).

```
global_image_loaded = 0
function LOADIMAGE(imagesrc) {  
    global_image_loaded = 0
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = imagesrc + "?" + new Date().getTime();

    img.onload = function() {
        global_image_loaded = 1;
    }

    if ( global_image_loaded = 1 ){
        return img;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This function works fine, until I try to draw the image to canvas with the following function:

```
function IMAGE(elementid, img, x, y, w, h) {
        var mode = 0;

        if ( w === undefined) {
            mode = 1;
        }

        if ( h === undefined) {
            mode = 1;
        }

        var canvas = document.getElementById(elementid);
        if ( ! canvas || ! canvas.getContext ) { return false; }
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        if ( mode === 1) {
            ctx.drawImage(img, x, y);
        }

        if (mode === 0) {
            ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, w, h);
        }
    }
```

This function works too but only if placed inside a loop, and ran several times. The image will display on the canvas, but it won't load an image when executed once. How can this even be possible, hasn't the img loaded already?

I think this is how it's done in JavaScript, unfortunately the img cannot be returned, and needs to always be displayed right afterwards? There seems to be no way to arbitrarily display an image.

```
   function PLACEIMAGE(elementid, imagesrc, x, y, w, h) {
    var mode = 0;

    if ( w === undefined) {
        mode = 1;
    }

    if ( h === undefined) {
        mode = 1;
    }

    var canvas = document.getElementById(elementid);
    if ( ! canvas || ! canvas.getContext ) { return false; }
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = imagesrc + "?" + new Date().getTime();
    img.onload = function() {

        if ( mode === 1) {
            ctx.drawImage(img, x, y);
        }

        if (mode === 0) {
            ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, w, h);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Boy this question sounds whiny. Your first function is flawed because `if ( global_image_loaded = 1 ){` will always set the variable and pass the condition. JavaScript is single threaded, but allows for asynchronous code execution. Your first function is an anti-pattern. If you were hoping to run some code after the image is loaded, you should pass a callback function to your `LOADIMAGE` function, and either invoke it if the image is `.complete`, or assign it to the `img.onload` property. Very short and simple.

Comment: And why is this tagged *crockford*?!

Comment: I did use onload and callbacks at first, but what I am trying to accomplish here is to load an image and return the img by calling a single function LOADIMAGE.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, what I was trying to do seems impossible or at least not very easy to do in Javascript 
for reference:

- [Call An Asynchronous Javascript Function Synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121902/call-an-asynchronous-javascript-function-synchronously).
- [sleep() in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136786/sleep-in-javascript)

ty