# jQuery resource for Win32 programmer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know programming in general but always been doing either Delphi, VB 6 or C#.net!  Now I must do web-dev and must do it fast! I haven't written a hello world in JavaScript yet and must learn jQuery because there are some charts that I must show in my web-app and looks like I must know JavaScript and jQuery to do that.

So I am looking for a jQuery resource that during its course or maybe at the first chapter gives us also a jump start on minimum JavaScript knowledge too. Some book or resource that I can hopefully sit and read through it in one day like 12 hours and after then learn enough to be able to use it and embed those darn charts and graphs into my web-app.

What do you suggest ?

Comment: You don't need jQuery for charts at all. There are other libraries like http://g.raphaeljs.com/ or http://d3js.org/ for that. As for JavaScript, I'd recommend https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide and http://eloquentjavascript.net/. Some of the tutorials at W3C (http://www.w3.org/wiki/Category:Tutorials) might also help to get you started with JS and DOM.

Comment: Must, do, now! Seriously, though, are you sure you don't just want to use a Javascript framework friendly to automation controls in your RAD/IDE? Ext.js and some others offer this type of support. Really, though, read [Javascript: The Definitive Guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596805531.do).

Comment: And if you're in a real crunch, hire somebody to help you do it and teach you as they go.

Comment: @FelixKling : Actually the libraries you mentioned are the same ones I want to use!  So "what knowledge " do I need yo have to use those libraries in my RubyRails project? They are the exact ones I wanted to use.

Comment: @FelixKling, oh, d3.js. Awesome, brilliant. Isn't necessarily the easiest package to pickup quickly, though... EDIT: Nevermind. *whistle*

Comment: @Jared: True, but it's awesome ;)

Comment: @BDotA: You have to know how JavaScript works, all the usual things any good tutorial explains. Especially make yourself familiar with the special `this` variable, that functions are first-class objects (can be passed around like any other value) and how callbacks work (scope). You have to know what the DOM is and how JS works together with the DOM. That's basically it. CSS is needed too but it should not be that big of a deal.

Comment: Also, try http://www.codecademy.com/learn, which is free. And http://www.udacity.com/. @FelixKling - You ain't kiddin'. That's some sweet sauce.

Comment: This might help with d3.js: http://nickqizhu.github.com/dc.js/ And for Raphael.js: http://www.oesmith.co.uk/morris.js/

Comment: *shameless self promotion* Maybe my link summary helps you as well (http://felix-kling.de/pages/javascript.html), but it's full of typos and grammar mistakes and is missing some things. I'm working on making it better ;) It's basically intended for people like you, who are new to the language but don't know exactly where to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basics of Javascript as a language are actually fairly straightforward, particularly if you've got a background in several other languages as you have. You'll find it immediately familiar with curly braces and other syntax that you'll recognise from elsewhere.

If you've worked with C#, you will hopefully have been exposed to lambda functions or closures. These are very important in Javascript, where they are key for the event-driven code that drives most websites, and in particular if you're using a library like jQuery, where they are used for virtually everything. You need to get a strong handle on how these functions work if you're going to make head or tail of jQuery.

The other thing to be aware of is that Javascript's object handling works a bit differently to the other languages you's used to. There are similarities, but if you try to write your classes and objects in the way you're used to, you will get some unexpected results. See [What type of language is JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120711/what-type-of-language-is-javascript) for more info on this.

Beyond that, I don't think you'll have a problem with the syntax.

The other thing to worry about is the DOM -- ie the browser's API which is accessed via Javascript. The DOM is not technically part of the Javascript language, but it is inextricably linked to it, and is as much part of the learning challenge as the language itself. jQuery abstracts a fair amount of the DOM away from you, but it still helps to know it.

Hope that helps get you started.