# JavaScript nested functions

Tags: javascript, closures

Why does

```
var spo = function(){
   var qq = function(){};
}
```

throw the error undefined is not a function when

```
var spo = function(){
   function qq(){};
}
```

does not?

---

More elaborate example throws the exact error: TypeError: undefined is not a function

node version v0.6.10 compiled on Ubuntu

```
spo = function(car){

        var q = 10;
        var s = 'fraggle';

        var qq = function(){
                console.log(s);
        }

        (function(){

                while(q){
                        console.log(q);
                        q--;
                }
                        qq.call();
                        car.call();
        })();


};


spo(function(){console.log('as intended');});
```

Comment: In which browser? How are you calling `qq`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  Could you provide so code to show when the undefined error occurs and when it does not?

Comment: Not knowing what your functions are actually doing... In the first case, the function is evaluated and assigned to qq.  In the second case, qq is never actually called - it's only being defined.

Comment: Also works for me. Please elaborate

Comment: I am using NODEJS some version of v8 let me make sure I am not doing something else wrong. I just put a super generic version of my problem. Let me get more information. I may have even found a real bug!

Comment: Somebody please correct me if I'm wrong, but does this have to do with qq being declared locally in the first answer and globally in the second answer?  If so then is qq undefined in the second answer because it's not declared locally in the closure scope?  Just a guess.

Comment: No it carries down the scope chain.

Comment: OK Ok after causing all this trouble I figured out that runjs is mucking up for some reason it does work sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this `qq` is assigned the function dynamically.

```
var spo = function(){
   // qq is undefined here
   var qq = function(){};
   // qq is defined here
}
```

On the other hand, in this case, qq is defined as a function which is visible everywhere in `spo`

```
var spo = function(){
   // qq is defined here
   function qq(){};
   // qq is defined here also
}
```

EDIT:
In your updated code the actual problem is visible, no semi colon after function which results in a wrong statement like given below

```
var qq = function(){}()(); // This is causing TypeError
```

Put a semi colon after function.

```
var qq = function(){
    console.log(s);
};  // you missed this semi colon

(function(){

     while(q){
         console.log(q);
         q--;
     }
     qq.call();
     car.call();
})();
```

Comment: I think you divined what the OP wanted

Comment: He answered a good question but I am getting errors with the var qq = function which I don`t believe that I should be now.

Comment: What lottery numbers should I play?

Answer (score 0):

You need a semicolon after your definition of `qq`. The engine is attempting to execute the result of calling your `qq` function with the argument of your anonymous function in the parentheses - if that's difficult to see, imagine removing the newlines and spaces separating the `qq` definition and the self-executing function.

```
var qq = function() {
}(function() {})();
```

Answer (score -3):

Try changing

```
qq.call();
```

to

```
qq();
```

As `qq` is a just a function and therefore not an "object" with the method `call`.

Comment: Actually, in Javascript functions *are* objects with methods. You are correct that `.call()` isn't necessary here, though.

Comment: It can be argued that Javascript has no concept of objects - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107464/is-javascript-object-oriented