# In JavaScript, how can I increment a variable that is inside a function from the outside?

Tags: javascript

I have tried declaring the variable outside the function but I get undefined.

```
      function scope() {
      let foo = 1;
      const bar = function() {
       return ++foo;
        }

        return bar;
        }

      const baz = scope();
      console.log(baz.foo);
      console.log(baz.foo);
```

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: You might want to make an object instead, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12610394/javascript-classes

Comment: `console.log(baz)`?

Comment: @zer00ne `baz` would return the function `bar`, `console.log(baz());` would return the return-value of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it, the Module pattern:

```
var Module = (function () {
//empty object
    var my = {};
//value
    my.value = 1;

  //method for incrementing the value 
    my.increment = function () {
        this.value++;
    };

    return my;
}());

Module.increment(); //increment the value from outside
console.log(Module.value) //log the new value
```

jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/9dr9xy23/5/

Comment: Good answer, but in your fiddle, `Module.moduleProperty` needs to be changed to `Module.value`.